# Open windows powershell when react is running

Tags: reactjs, powershell

I have started learning react. I have installed and created a new todo-app. I am using windows 10.

In windows powershell how can I get the prompt back when the react is already running.

This is what I get in powershell -

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view todoapp in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.34:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Do I need to open a separate cmd or is there any way to get back the command prompt in powershell while react is running.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to stop the development server (ctrl-c?) or open a separate command prompt.

Comment: Yes I also think so. I was just looking at terminal emulator for windows which might split the pane vertically.

Answer (score 0):

After typing PowerShell in windows search hold `shift` while pressing `enter` to open a new instance of PowerShell